# Update in SQL Server , how does it work with selected update?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I made this simple example of a complex update I did but as an Oracle developer I am amazed that this actually works since I am not joining the select that gets the update value, only in the WHERE EXISTS part.

So my question is how does this work? How does it acually update the correct record when its not joined?

```
UPDATE dbo.gg_ddl_changes_mssql
SET gg_ddl_changes_mssql.column_id       = a.ordinal_position, 
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.default_value   = a.default_value, 
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.nullable        = a.is_nullable, 
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.data_type       = a.data_type, 
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.data_length     = a.character_maximum_length, 
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.data_precision  = a.numeric_precision,
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.data_scale      = a.numeric_scale, 
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.date_precision  = a.datetime_precision, 
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.pk_id           = a.pk_id, 
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.pk_name         = a.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
    gg_ddl_changes_mssql.last_updated    = GETDATE()
FROM (SELECT c.ordinal_position, 
             LEFT(c.column_default, 2000) as "default_value", 
             c.is_nullable, c.data_type, 
             c.character_maximum_length, 
             c.numeric_precision, 
             c.numeric_scale, 
             c.datetime_precision, 
             pc.ordinal_position as "pk_id", 
             pc.constraint_name
   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables  AS t, 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS p
  ON c.table_name = p.table_name
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE pc
  ON (p.constraint_name = pc.constraint_name
  AND c.column_name     = pc.column_name)
 WHERE t.table_type       = 'BASE TABLE' 
   AND t.table_name       = c.table_name 
   AND t.table_schema     = c.table_schema 
   AND p.constraint_type  = 'PRIMARY KEY'
   ) as a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables  AS t1, 
                     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c1
              LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS p1
                ON c1.table_name = p1.table_name
              LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE pc1
                ON (p1.constraint_name = pc1.constraint_name
                AND c1.column_name     = pc1.column_name)
               WHERE t1.table_type       = 'BASE TABLE' 
                 AND c1.table_schema     = gg_ddl_changes_mssql.table_schema
                 AND c1.table_name       = gg_ddl_changes_mssql.table_name
                 AND c1.column_name      = gg_ddl_changes_mssql.column_name
                 AND t1.table_name       = c1.table_name 
                 AND t1.table_schema     = c1.table_schema 
                 AND p1.constraint_type  = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                 AND ( c1.ordinal_position             != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.column_id
                   OR  LEFT(c1.column_default, 2000)   != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.default_value
                   OR  c1.is_nullable                  != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.nullable
                   OR  c1.data_type                    != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.data_type
                   OR  c1.character_maximum_length     != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.data_length
                   OR  c1.numeric_precision            != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.data_precision 
                   OR  c1.numeric_scale                != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.data_scale
                   OR  c1.datetime_precision           != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.date_precision
                   or  pc1.ordinal_position            != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.pk_id
                   or  pc1.constraint_name             != gg_ddl_changes_mssql.pk_name))
```

In Oracle we would get a value as the select value would return many values if there is more than one record in tableY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
UPDATE x
SET x.column1 = y.column1
FROM dbo.tableX x
JOIN dbo.tableY y ON x.primary_key_col = y.primary_key_col
WHERE x.column1 != y.column1
```

**Update:**

```
UPDATE t
SET column_id       = c.ordinal_position, 
    default_value   = LEFT(c.column_default, 2000), 
    nullable        = c.is_nullable, 
    data_type       = c.data_type, 
    data_length     = c.character_maximum_length, 
    data_precision  = c.numeric_precision,
    data_scale      = c.numeric_scale, 
    date_precision  = c.datetime_precision, 
    pk_id           = pc.ordinal_position, 
    pk_name         = pc.constraint_name, 
    last_updated    = GETDATE()
FROM dbo.gg_ddl_changes_mssql t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ta ON ta.table_schema = t.table_schema 
                                 AND ta.table_name = t.table_name
                                 AND ta.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c ON ta.table_name = c.table_name 
                                 AND ta.table_schema = c.table_schema
                                 AND c.column_name = t.column_name
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS p ON c.table_name = p.table_name 
                                                AND p.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE pc ON p.constraint_name = pc.constraint_name 
                                                AND c.column_name = pc.column_name
WHERE 
         c.ordinal_position             != t.column_id
     OR  LEFT(c.column_default, 2000)   != t.default_value
     OR  c.is_nullable                  != t.nullable
     OR  c.data_type                    != t.data_type
     OR  c.character_maximum_length     != t.data_length
     OR  c.numeric_precision            != t.data_precision 
     OR  c.numeric_scale                != t.data_scale
     OR  c.datetime_precision           != t.date_precision
     OR  ISNULL(pc.ordinal_position, -1)!= t.pk_id
     OR  ISNULL(pc.constraint_name, '') != t.pk_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers but in my real case the subselect is 4 tables joined differently. I guess I could do it this way but in my world that would be a mess to read...but then I am a Oracle guy ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) This is how I figured it would look like (or kind of look like) but that would have taken me forever and I wouldn't be 100% I did it right. This works, its tested :-)

Answer (score 1):

You unnecessarily making a Complex Query

```
UPDATE X
SET X.column1 = Y.column1
FROM tableX X
INNER JOIN tableY Y
ON X.primary_key_col = Y.primary_key_col
WHERE X.column1 != Y.column1
```

Comment: Yep, your answers are very similar and both are useful :-)